# JAVA - Store classes that implement Interface then return instance

Tags: java, generics

I would like to know how I could store classes that implement IModule into a Set, then return the instance of the class, not an instance of IModule. For example, I want something like this to work:

```
ModuleService m = new ModuleService();
m.register(new CoreModule(this));
m.getRegistration(CoreModule.class);
```

ModuleService#getRegistration should return CoreModule, not an IModule. I've tried using Capture generics and T, but you can't use T on fields, and using them on the class wouldn't make much sense.

Using ? generic:

```
private Set<? extends IModule> modules = new HashSet<>();

public ModuleService(STBot bot) {
    this.bot = bot;
}

public <T extends IModule> boolean register(T module) {
    if (modules.stream().noneMatch(m -> m.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(module.getId()))) {
        modules.add(module);
        return true;
    } else return false;
}

public Optional<? extends IModule> getRegistration(Class clazz) {
    return modules.stream().filter(m -> m.getClass().equals(clazz)).findFirst();
}

public Set<? extends IModule> getModules() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(modules);
}
```

But that errors at modules.add(module); because T is not ?, none of what I tried actually works which is why I'm asking here

Comment: @user edited the post

Comment: Just use `Set<IModule>` The wildcard means that all the IModules in that set are of some type that you don't know, which probably isn't what you want here.

Comment: Also, your `getRegistration` method could be made to look like `<T extends IModule> Optional<T> getRegistration(Class<T> clazz) {...}`

Comment: Yeah but I can't use that on Set so I wouldn't be able to store it like that

Comment: Hmm? What can't you use on `Set`? It's perfectly all right to use `Set<IModule>` without a bounded wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straight forward way to implement that

```
public class ModuleService {
    private Map<Class<?>, IModule> modules = new HashMap<>();

    public void register(IModule module) {
        modules.put(module.getClass(), module);
    }

    public <T extends IModule> T getRegistration(Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        return (T) modules.get(clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, just changed it to return an Optional<T> instead. Could you explain what the Class<? extends T> is though?

Comment: `Class<? extends T>` is simply how you describe the Class of an object that must be an instance of T.